# How to pull week's worth of appointments with CURDATE + 7 Day INTERVAL

Tags: php, mysql

I have prepared a little pull request to pull appointments for Today from the DB:

```
$getAppointmentsToday = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE DATE(appointment_date) = CURDATE()");

$getAppointmentsToday->execute();
```

I tried modifying this statement to also pull appointments for the following 7 days, but running into some trouble:

```
$getAppointmentsWeek = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE DATE(appointment_date) = (CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAYS)");

$getAppointmentsWeek->execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `BETWEEN` operator for this :

```
... 
WHERE DATE(appointment_date) 
    BETWEEN CURDATE() 
    AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

You are now checking the date CURDATE()+7 days, instead of the date interval. Use:

```
SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE DATE(appointment_date) <= (CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAYS) AND DATE(appointment_date) >= CURDATE()
```